# JSTL to retrieve value from 2 map

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have 2 map. 1 is from applicationScope and another 1 is from sessionScope.

applicationScopeMap Object:

```
{
    "1":{"id":"1","name":"SampleName 1","mobile":"9912345678"}
    "2":{"id":"2","name":"SampleName 2","mobile":"7878776876"}
    "3":{"id":"3","name":"SampleName 3","mobile":"8576868778"}
}
```

sessionScopeMap Object:

```
{
    "id":1
}
```

Using JSTL how to print the value based on sessionScope?

I tried like converting the session id to string by c:set,

```
<c:set var="idAsString">${sessionScope.sessionName.id}</c:set>
```

then passing in the forEach.

```
<c:forEach items="${applicationScope.applicationScopeMap[idAsString]}" var="item">
    ${item.name}
</c:forEach>
```

I'm getting error.

Could you please help...

Comment: Try `${sessionScope.sessionName.id.toString()}` in your `set`. Now you are adding an integer or long.

Comment: maybe `${sessionScope.sessionScopeMap.id}` instead  of `sessionName`